# Como enviar um SOAP em C?

Tags: c, web-service, soap

Como é que eu faço para enviar um SOAP em C?

Eu tenho um Web Service que consome SOAP e tenho que enviar esse SOAP em C.

Como é que eu posso fazer isso? Existe alguma API ou tenho de criar uma biblioteca?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode-se utilizar a API [`WWSAPI`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wsw/portal), como mencionado na [resposta do Toby Mosque](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/53327/6454), para fazer isso você deve basicamente criar um [*proxy* de serviço](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wsw/service-proxy) através da função [`WsCreateServiceProxy`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/webservices/nf-webservices-wscreateserviceproxy) e depois de criada, utilizar a função [`WsOpenServiceProxy`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/webservices/nf-webservices-wsopenserviceproxy) passando como parâmetro uma estrutura [`WS_ENDPOINT_ADDRESS`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/webservices/ns-webservices-ws_endpoint_address) que conterá as informações necessárias para se conectar-se ao serviço.

Quando não for mais necessário o uso desse serviço pode-se chamar a função [`WsCloseServiceProxy`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/webservices/nf-webservices-wscloseserviceproxy) para fechar a comunicação e liberar a memória associada a ele com [`WsFreeServiceProxy`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/webservices/nf-webservices-wsfreeserviceproxy).

Na página abaixo você pode encontrar *links* para todos os recursos disponíveis para realizar esse tipo de conexão. MSDN.

- [Connecting native C/C++ code and Web Services using WWSAPI](https://web.archive.org/web/20150915192312/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/nikolad/archive/2009/04/06/connecting-c-c-and-web-services.aspx)

Existem também bibliotecas que podem fazer esse trabalho por você. Como por exemplo, o [**csoap**](http://csoap.sourceforge.net/docs.php), uma biblioteca cliente/servidor para SOAP escrita em C puro.

- [Documentação](http://csoap.sourceforge.net/docs.php)
- [Cliente SOAP - exemplo](http://csoap.sourceforge.net/docs/snapshot/libsoap-doc-api/html/csoap_client_page.html)
- [Servidor SOAP - exemplo](http://csoap.sourceforge.net/docs/snapshot/libsoap-doc-api/html/csoap_server_page.html)

Uma outra alternativa é o projeto [**Apache Axis**](https://axis.apache.org/) do Apache Fondation.

- [Versão em C - Apache Axis2/C](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/c/core/)

  - [Documentação](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/c/core/docs/index.html)
  - [Convenções de codificação](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/c/core/coding_conventions.html)
- [Versão em Java - Apache Axis2/Java](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/)

  - [Índice](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/toc.html)

Comment: Muito boa resposta

Comment: @JorgeB. Obrigado. Consegui encontrar [aqui](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/article.php/c17915/Querying-Bing-Using-the-New-Windows-7-Web-Services-C-API.htm) um artigo que mostra de um modo mais nítido como usar essa API, é C++, mas dá para captar a ideia. =)

Comment: Já agora a csoap dá me erros em quase todas os headers...

Answer (score 1):

@JorgeB, para conectar uma aplicação C/C++ a um WebService, você precisa utilizar a WWSAPI.

Para mais informações você pode olhar o seguinte site:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/dd430462(v=vs.85).aspx